# Why would replacing a parameter with a local variable speed up a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that has two DATE parameters, as such:

```
@startDate DATE,
@endDate DATE
```

While developing the sproc it was great (< 1 second). Moved it into a stored procedure as a child and when I ran it again, it takes minutes to run (2 to be exact).

I ran into this before (which I thought was some anomaly that I didn't pursue back then) so I tried the last "hack" that worked:

```
DECLARE @sDate DATE = CAST(@startDate AS DATE);
DECLARE @eDate DATE = CAST(@endDate AS DATE);
```

And sure enough, back to < 1s return times.

I have tried everything to figure this out and nothing seems to work. I can't find differences anywhere that changes anything. The values are exactly the same, not matter how many different ways I try to slice it.

I have also tried:

```
SET @startDate = CAST(@startDate AS DATE);
SET @startDate = CONVERT(date, @startDate, 101)
```

And I have tried re-declaring them (using any method) in the parent sproc.

It only works if I re-declare the variables in the child sproc.

So, why would re-declaring a variable of the same type, result in such an extreme difference in performance?

#### UPDATE - It *Is* Parameter Sniffing

I didn't originally think so, but all evidence points to the fact that it is, even though I haven't been able to fix it with normal methods that typically either work or help identify it. ***Except*** replacing it with a local variable which with the help from all the posters below would indicate it **has** to be parameter sniffing.

---

First Update

I don't think this is parameter sniffing - which was my first thought. This is what I have done to test this:

- Changed parameters (add/remove)
- Added additional criteria to the query
- Added OPTION recompile
- SET ARITHABORT ON
- Drop/Created old and new indexes

The changes above had no impact on the query.

Comment: Because it changes the execution plan.  That is where you have to look.  Perhaps it is also causing the query to be recompiled.

Comment: Did you run this proc/query 10+ times and get max/min/avg runtimes?

Comment: Doesn't this have to do with parameter sniffing?

Comment: You will need to add more data and examples  as well.One more reason can be , your query might be face data type conversions

Comment: Please check this link to know more on how to improve question(https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: This article should help explain what you are seeing. https://www.sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2007/11/27/parameter-sniffing/ Make sure you follow the article and read parts 2 & 3 as well.

Comment: Parameter sniffing, rebinding parameters to local variables is common scenario.

Comment: @TonyBasallo It's a workaround to parameter sniffing problem. Common scenario. Please check second link in my answer.

Comment: It's not parameter sniffing - at least not any kind I've encountered. I thought so at first to, however, I have tried every known trick to break this and nothing changes. I edited the question with what I have tried. Perhaps I missed a trick to ensure it is or is not parameter sniffing.

Comment: Here is the biggest issue. You state it isn't parameter sniffing and reading your question multiple times perhaps it isn't...but I am not convinced of that. It sure sounds like classic sniffing to me. The reason nobody can answer this yet is because you have not provided any actual details. We have no idea what your table(s) design is or what the procedure(s) in question are doing. Follow the link provided by TheGameiswar and then post some real details. Without that the best we can do is guess.

Comment: Yep you put in big bold text that **It's Not Parameter Sniffing** and then provide a list of things which in no way disprove that it is parameter sniffing. But it may not be the type of parameter sniffing where a plan is compiled for one value and then executed with another. It may be that the plan is compiled and executed with the same value but being compiled with the actual value gives a different (in your case worse) plan. In which case hopefully a statistics update would do the trick.

Comment: Yeah, if you fixed it by replacing parameters with local variables, it was parameter sniffing.   None of your reasons for ruling it out are as strong as this one reason why it IS.   If it WASN'T parameter sniffing, replacing the parameters with local variables would not have worked.

Comment: Thanks for everyone for the help.
@MartinSmith I'll try updating statistics and see what happens.

Comment: @TabAlleman, trust me, I thought (think?!?) it was parameter sniffing too. But every trick I've ever done or read about hasn't "fixed" it (except the local parameter). I'm going to try the statistics and see. You all are probably right. This one has been messing with me, I guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a "parameter sniffing" workaround. I recommend to read: **[Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)**

> *Parameters and Variables*
>
> Consider the Orders table in the Northwind database, and these three procedures:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE List_orders_1 AS
   SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE OrderDate > '20000101'
go
CREATE PROCEDURE List_orders_2 @fromdate datetime AS
   SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE OrderDate > @fromdate
go
CREATE PROCEDURE List_orders_3 @fromdate datetime AS
   DECLARE @fromdate_copy datetime
   SELECT @fromdate_copy = @fromdate
   SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE OrderDate > @fromdate_copy
go
```

> In the first procedure, the date is a constant, which means that the SQL Server only needs to consider exactly this case. It interrogates the statistics for the Orders table, which indicates that there are no rows with an OrderDate in the third millennium. (All orders in the Northwind database are from 1996 to 1998.) Since statistics are statistics, SQL Server cannot be sure that the query will return no rows at all, why it makes an estimate of one single row.
>
> In the case of List_orders_2, the query is against a variable, or more precisely a parameter. When performing the optimisation, SQL Server knows that the procedure was invoked with the value 2000-01-01. Since it does not any perform flow analysis, it can't say for sure whether the parameter will have this value when the query is executed. Nevertheless, it uses the input value to come up with an estimate, which is the same as for List_orders_1: one single row. This strategy of looking at the values of the input parameters when optimising a stored procedure is known as parameter sniffing.
>
> **In the last procedure, it's all different. The input value is copied to a local variable, but when SQL Server builds the plan, it has no understanding of this and says to itself I don't know what the value of this variable will be.**
>
> ...
>
> *Key Points*
>
> In this section, we have learned three very important things:
>
> -A constant is a constant, and when a query includes a constant, SQL Server can use the value of the constant with full trust, and even take such shortcuts to not access a table at all, if it can infer from constraints that no rows will be returned.
>
> -For a parameter, SQL Server does not know the run-time value, but it "sniffs" the input value when compiling the query.
>
> -**For a local variable, SQL Server has no idea at all of the run-time value, and applies standard assumptions. (Which the assumptions are depends on the operator and what can be deduced from the presence of unique indexes.)**

And second great article **[Parameter Sniffing Problem and Possible Workarounds](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/turgays/2013/09/10/parameter-sniffing-problem-and-possible-workarounds/)**

Comment: I thought it was at first too, however, I have tried every known trick to break this and nothing changes. I edited the question with what I have tried. Perhaps I missed a trick to ensure it is or is not parameter sniffing.

Comment: I usually fix parameter sniffing by redeclaring parameters, so I think you are 100% right.